# pass array to method with condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Im using the following code to split array which is working,
I need to pass some value when array

for examle here is split the value to array

```
var myArr = val.split(/(\s+)/);
```

and if array in place 2 is empty I need to use the method like following
pass empty array in second arg

```
  var val = process.run(myArr[0], [], options);
```

if the array place 2 is not empty I need to pass it like following

```
var val = process.run(myArr[0], [myArr[2]], options);
```

The second arg is array inside arry with the value of 2

there is nice way to do it instead of if on the method ?

Comment: what is wrong with `myArr[2].lenght >0 ? [myArr[2]] : []`?

Comment: I'd probably put this functionality in the method itself, or a helper. That way you don't separate the logic the function *must have* in order to run correctly, and you don't have to remember to do that in the mainline code.

Comment: @DaveNewton - not sure that I got what do you mean can you provide example?

Comment: @Dalorzo - do you mean inside the function parameter? can you provide complete example as answer and i'll try it...

Comment: what is `process.run` function?

Comment: @Grundy - this is just internal function noting spacial ...

Comment: i just can't find doc for it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) or this some custom?

Comment: @Grundy - this is custom...

Comment: if so, Mark suggest move this checking inside this function, so for example you can pass to it just `myArr` like `var val = process.run(myArr, options)` and check inside this function what come from myArr

Comment: is `myArr[2]` an array? is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a function, as [Dave Newton recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262443/pass-array-to-method-with-condition#comment54325987_33262443). I could take the initial `val` and `options` as an argument and return the result of `process.run`:

```
function runProcess(val, options) {
    var myArr = val.split(/(\s+)/);
    var argArray = [];
    if(myArr[2]) {
        argArray.push(myArr[2]);
    }
    return process.run(myArr[0], argArray, options);
}
```

Since I don't know what the function exactly does, the name of the function and variables are pretty arbitrary. Feel free to change them to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If `myArr[2]` is a flat array and will always be flat, why not...

```
var val = process.run(myArr[0], [].concat(myArr[2]), options);
```

Comment: from OP - `myArr` is result for split, so it is array of string, and if `myArr[2]` is empty string you pass `[""]` instead `[]`

Comment: Where is that in the OP? I see where he says if `myArr[2]` is empty then empty array.

Comment: `var myArr = val.split(/(\s+)/);` i think here clear :-) [_The **split()** method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: sorry, still not getting it. in your first comment are you saying that the OP is saying that he wants to pass `[""]` instead of `[]` when `myArr[2]` is empty? If so, then I still don't see where he's saying that.

Comment: nope :-) i mean that **you**, i.e. your code,  pass `[""]` if `myArr[2]` is empty string. But OP expect that would be passed `[]`